# Fitting missing points to a dataset

Tags: missing-data, fitting, data-imputation

I've been assigned to fit some missing values into a large dataset, and I've come across a problem. I've finally got a function describing my data (for simplicity say y=2x^2). Now, for every value of x, I have multiple values of y (so there is variance in the data). I'm using R, and used the `nls(y~ax^b)` function to find the relationship (returns y=2x^2). I can use `deviance()` to find the deviance of my fitted model.

My question is, how do I use the deviance and the function to assign values to missing data points? That is, for some x values, I'm missing y. I don't think I can simply put in the value of y that my function returns, since this does not incorporate the variance. For example, if I had missing values for x={1,1,2,3,3,3,3,3}, fitting y={2,2,8,18,18,18,18,18} does not seem right. So how to I incorporate the variance to fit values of y such that my fitted values will conserve the measured variance?